# Getting constructor to work initial variables

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StageA {

    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StageA stageA = new StageA();
        stageA.runMenu();

    }

    private void runMenu() {
        char selection;

        do {
            displayMenu();
            selection = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            processSelection(selection);
        } while (selection != 'x');

    }

    private static void displayMenu() {

        System.out.printf("\n  **** Ozzey Attraction Menu ****\n");
        System.out.printf("A : Add New Attraction\n");
        System.out.printf("B : View Attraction\n");
        System.out.printf("C : List All Attractions\n");
        System.out.printf("D : Sell Ticket\n");
        System.out.printf("E : Refund Ticket\n");
        System.out.printf("F : Remove Attraction\n");
        System.out.printf("X : Exit\n\n");

        System.out.printf("Enter selection : ");
    }

    private static void createAttraction() {


        System.out.printf("Enter attraction description : ");
        String description = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Enter cost of a Ticket  : ");
        double ticketCost = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.printf("Is this a supervised tour ? [Y/N] :\n");
        char chosen = sc.nextLine().to Lowercase().charAt(0);

        System.out.printf("What is maximum permitted tour group size?\n");
        int maxGroupSize = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.printf("Enter the agency contact details:\n ");
        String contactDetails = sc.nextLine();


        int counter = 0;
        String[] storedActivities;
        String guide, rating;

        switch (chosen) {

            case 'y':

                System.out.printf("How many activity are there?\n");
                int activities = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                while (activities < 1) {

                    System.out.printf("Please enter valid number of activities great than zero \n");
                    System.out.printf("How many activity are there?\n");
                    activities = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                }

                storedActivities = new String[activities];

                while (activities > counter) {

                    System.out.printf("Please enter  activity #%d: ", counter);
                    storedActivities[counter] = sc.nextLine();
                    counter++;
                }
                break;
            case 'n':

                System.out.printf("Enter the instruction guide:\n");
                guide = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("Enter the difficulty rating:\n");
                rating = sc.nextLine();
                break;

            default:

                System.out.printf("Please Enter valid answer ");
                System.out.printf("Is this a supervised tour ? [Y/N] :\n");
                chosen = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
                break;

        }

        Attraction attraction = new Attraction(description, ticketCost, maxGroupSize, contactDetails, chosen, guide, rating, storedActivities[counter]);
    }

    private static void processSelection(char selection) {

        switch (selection) {

            case 'a':

                createAttraction();


                break;
            case 'b':
                System.out.println("b");
                break;
            case 'c':
                System.out.println("c");
                break;
            case 'd':
                break;
            case 'e':
                System.out.println("e");
                break;
            case 'f':
                System.out.println("f");
                break;
            case 'x':
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again\n");

        }

    }
}


public class Attraction {
    private String description, contactDetails, guide, rating;
    private double ticketCost;
    private int maxGroupSize;
    private char chosen;
    private String storedActivities;



    public Attraction(String description, double ticketCost, int maxGroupSize, String contactDetails,
                      char chosen, String guide, String rating, String storedActivities) {


        this.description = description;
        this.ticketCost = ticketCost;
        this.maxGroupSize = maxGroupSize;
        this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
        this.chosen = chosen;
        this.guide = guide;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.activities = storedActivities;
    }

}
```

I cannot get my constructor to work

```
Attraction attraction = new Attraction(description, ticketCost, maxGroupSize, contactDetails, chosen, guide, rating, storedActivities[counter]);
```

where every I move it to I cannot get into to work I tried while if  statement and changed to a switch statement but I get the same error  error I getting cannot resolve variable rating, guide and `storedActivities[counter]` any help would be appreciated

I can only use a single array and the questions are in order I need to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because there is a risk you will not have initialised your variables by the time you attempt to instantiate your `Attraction` instance.

The following lines declare your variables but at this point they have not been assigned a value:-

```
String[] storedActivities;
String guide, rating;
```

Note that if your code enters either the `default` or the `'n'` case in your switch statement, some of these variables remain unset. You need to fix this before the compiler will be satisfied that it has all the information it needs to create your `Attraction` object.

Your solution is down to coding preference & needs. You could assign a default value to these parameters, use tail recursion to prevent incorrect answers from the scanner, or provide an alternative constructor if not all details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this would be because your variables are not intialised at the start.

Think about it: The vars `rating, guide and storedActivities[]` will not be intialised if the `chosen` = anything **other than** `y` or `n`. The JVM automatically senses this and `throws` an error automatically.

What I suggest you do is set them to a default size (the array) or a default value, so that this error will not occur. Having the default value also means you could automatically override any incorrect values given by the user.